# .NET MVC 4.5 rewrite index route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

Currently I have a controller like this:

```
class AccountController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

It's ok except one part that user when go to this page will have this url: 
`http://myhost/account/index`, which is unwanted. How can I have `http://myhost/account` only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could do the trick

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Account",
    url: "account/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

It could be also done with Attribute routing decorating with `[Route]` the method you want to be the default.

Comment: Is your solution mvc compatible ? I tried with `[Route]` but it gave me 404:

`[Route("")]
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}`

Comment: I'd say it might depends on if you already use attributed routing. How do you currently define routes on your app?

Comment: It follows the convention of `{controller}/{action}`. I didn't change anything. Using owning startup class but in startup class constructor, only method called was MapSignalR(). This means 

`myhost/account/index` will be mapped to AccountController -> Index instance method.

The rest of the controller only accepts post request. The reason of this is because the app is devided into sections, each is a medium size SPA, in which you only care about the controller you are in, not the action.

Comment: @bigopon: add the route I wrote at the very top of your routes definition so it find it first

Comment: Sorry for newbie's lack of knowledge, Is the suggestion for MVC ? Since it looks very hard for me to find a way to configure routes in. If it was, can you share some code how to configure please.

Comment: @bigopon: paste your routes configurations and I'll help you to modify them

Comment: @bigopon: do you have a RouteConfig.cs file?

Comment: Ok, so it was another noob problem. The solution has both `Global.asax` and `Startup.cs` but I ignored `global.asax` as I thought `Startup.cs` will do it. Just add the route there and works as expected. Thks for your help.